# Create a file that was declared by URI if it doesn't exist

Tags: java, file

I am trying to declare a File but keep getting a NullPointerException because the file doesn't exist. I want to create it, but I'm getting the exception before I can even check. I think it's because the file I am trying to create is in the resource folder. Here is my MCV:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Stack {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File testFile = new File(Stack.class.getResource("/file.txt").toString());
        if(!testFile.exists()) {
            try {
                testFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("file exists");
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen other examples where they do

```
URL fileAsURL = Stack.class.getResource("/file.txt");
if(URL == null){
   ...
}else{
    File testFile = new File(fileAsURL.toURI());
}
```

but they literally always put "..." in the if statement for what to do when the URL is null and I have no idea what you're supposed to do to create it if its null.

Comment: `getResource()` will return `null` if the given resource does not exists on CLASSPATH...

Comment: Ok I understand that. So how can I create it when it doesn't exist?

Comment: You cannot create files on the CLASSPATH, as it might be in a JAR archive... You can create files on disks only

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. I guess I'll just save all my files in some folder that gets pointed to by a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is I cannot do what I am trying to do because the CLASSPATH might be the JAR file my program is running off of. I will change the directory I am trying to write to so it is on the disk somewhere.